# SELECT bestseller books from DB

Tags: abap, opensql

I'm new on ABAP, and I'm trying to get the "best seller" products, so, I need to do a SUM with a GROUP BY product ID, I'm trying by this way but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT SUM(CANTIDAD) into (suma) FROM ZVENTAS_DETALLE GROUP BY ID_PRODUCTO.
```

Any help? thanks

**UPDATE**

Now, I'm trying to do this with Inner Join to show Product NAme and Total Sales, So, I have this code:

```
SELECT SUM( CANTIDAD ) vd~ID_PRODUCTO prd~STOCK_PRODUCTO
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE tabla
  FROM ZVENTAS_DETALLE AS vd
  INNER JOIN ZPRODUCTOS AS prd ON prd~ID_PRODUCTO = vd~ID_PRODUCTO
  GROUP BY vd~ID_PRODUCTO.
  LOOP at tabla into ven.
    WRITE:/ ven~PRODUCTO_NOMBRE.
  ENDLOOP.
```

So, I get this error
[image]

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: It "doesn't work", what do you mean exactly, what do you get? A compilation error, or it runs but the result is not what you expect, or what else?

Comment: According to what I see, you need to add PRD~STOCK_PRODUCTO to the GROUP BY, after VD~ID_PRODUCTO. Check the errors in the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_data, 
  id_producto type zventas_detalle-id_producto,
  suma type zventas_detalle-suma,
END OF ty_data.

DATA it_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_data. " <-- The internal table

SELECT id_producto SUM( cantidad ) as suma 
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_data
FROM ZVENTAS_DETALLE GROUP BY id_producto.

SORT it_data BY suma DESCENDING. "<-- The best sellers will be the first
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: use `id_producto type zventas_detalle-id_producto,`

Comment: @SandraRossi Done. Best regards.

Comment: thanks for your help, I just updated the original post, could you help me? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use that form:

```
SELECT id_producto, SUM( cantidad ) as sum
  FROM zventas_detalle
 GROUP BY id_producto
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_bestselling) .
```